# Effect of doubly stochastic matrix on vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $D$ be a $N \times N$ doubly stochastic matrix, $x$ be a $N$ dimensional vector.

What is the relation between $\Vert Dx \Vert_2$ and $\Vert x \Vert_2$?

In addition if $\Vert x \Vert_2=1$, what can I say about $\Vert Dx \Vert_2$?

Comment: If $\|x\|_2$...what? You , miss something in your second question.

Comment: @julien Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that a doubly stochastic matrix $D$ has operator norm 1. But that's not 
because of its eigenvalues, because $\|P\|=1$  is false for a general stochastic matrix $P$.

Rather, from the [Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff_polytope_and_Birkhoff.E2.80.93von_Neumann_theorem) 
we know that $D$ is a convex combination of permutation (norm one) matrices,
and hence $\|D\|\leq 1$.

Alternatively, if $D$ is doubly stochastic then $D^* D$ is stochastic and therefore
its eigenvalues are bounded by one in modulus. [Therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101208/how-does-one-prove-that-the-spectral-norm-is-less-than-or-equal-to-the-frobenius/101213#101213) $\|D\|=1$.

Answer (score -1):

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40320/proof-that-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-stochastic-matrix-is-1), we have that the largest eigenvalue of a stochastic matrix is $1$. Hence, we have
$$\Vert Dx \Vert_2 \leq \Vert x \Vert_2$$